# How can I solve "DH_KEY_TOO_SMALL" in Python Requests

Tags: python, ssl, https, python-requests, router

I want to access my router using Python Requests. But, am getting this error "requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='192.168.1.20', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /login.cgi?uri=/index.html (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: DH_KEY_TOO_SMALL] dh key too small (_ssl.c:997)')))" how can I fix this?
Please help.
My code is below:

```
import requests

def main():
    URL = 'https://192.168.1.20/login.cgi?uri=/index.html'
    r = requests.get(URL, verify=False)
    print(r)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: DH_KEY_TOO_SMALL has nothing to do with hostnames. The server is using EDH parameters that are too small and thus insecure.

Comment: I was struggling to fix hostnames... error. So I mistakenly wrote it here. Anyway, thanks for rectifying. Can you solve the problem("DH_KEY_TOO_SMALL")?